# How to implement a server for android Restful client application?

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest, rest-client

I want to develop an android REST client application. I watched this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE).  I don't know about implementing a web server and organizing data in the server and performing CRUD operations on the data from the application. I tried to do some research on the internet but I failed to make google to understand my query. So can anyone help me out with this problem by posting some useful links here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: so what was your google query like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement server in any technology like Ruby and Rails, J2EE or node.js.

I prefer node.js and Express.

See this blog link for details:

http://pixelhandler.com/posts/develop-a-restful-api-using-nodejs-with-express-and-mongoose